# Parse a string value using mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a value in a column in this manner

"id=Clarizen,ou=GROUP,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net|id=devendrat,ou=USER,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net"

I want to extract group name and user name from this string and will store it into separate columns of another table.

Desired result:

Clarizen as Groupname
devendrat as Username

Please help

Comment: You want to do this using SQL - or a specific programming language?

Comment: i want to do it using mysql only

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for CharIndex and Substring option.
The following works for T-SQL. I am not sure about the Syntax in My SQL

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,CHARINDEX(',',ColumnName) - 1),'ID=','') 
       AS Groupname,
       REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('|',ColumnName),
       LEN(ColumnName)),1,
       CHARINDEX(',',ColumnName) - 1),'|ID=','') AS Username
```

Answer (score -1):

(sorry this is C# I overlooked that you are using mysql, so the answer is useless to you but I'll leave it here unless someone is to remove it)

Using string split can get the job done, here is something that I whipped together, it won't be optimal but it definately works!

```
        string parse_me = "id=Clarizen,ou=GROUP,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net|id=devendrat,ou=USER,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net";

        string[] lines = parse_me.Split(',');

        List<string> variables = new List<string>();
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] pair = line.Split('=');
            //Console.WriteLine(line);
            variables.Add(pair[0]);
            values.Add(pair[1]);
        }

        string group = "";
        string user = "";

        if (variables.Count == values.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < variables.Count; ++i )
            {
                Console.Write(variables[i]);
                Console.Write(" : ");
                Console.WriteLine(values[i]);

                if (variables[i] == "ou")
                {
                    if (group == "")
                    {
                        group = values[i];
                    }
                    else if (user == "")
                    {
                        user = values[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Group is: " + group);
        Console.WriteLine("User is: " + user);

        Console.ReadLine();
```